# How can I check for events during a while loop?

Tags: javascript, events, while-loop

I am trying to make a system where you can call a function, and said function will wait until a key is pressed before the function would end, therefore halting the program until the next key is pressed.

I've tried using a variable within a while loop, however, if I try to change that variable on a keydown event, it won't change if the loop is running.

```
    var x = true;
    myFunction (event) {
        x = false;
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction);
    function wait () {
        x = true;
        while (x);
    }
    wait();
```

This doesn't return any error messages, however, the program never continues after hitting a key.

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, so `while (x);` will stop the code indefinitely. `"therefore halting the program"` this is something you never want to do in javascript. JS is a single threaded event driven language, so halting the program execution (and then resuming) is not possible.

Comment: @Olian04 I realized this, however, I am trying to change x after a keypress, however, I'm not sure how to check for a keypress during a loop.

Comment: There is no way to check for a keypress "during a loop" in JavaScript. It uses what is called the "event loop" to manage code execution. Bottom line, events get queued and wait for the current call stack to be empty before they can be processed. So your `while` loop actually keeps the events handler from ever running, since the call stack never clears. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCOL7MC4Pl0) are extremely good explanations of the event loop from past JSConf talks.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really how you write javascript, I'm afraid. What you're doing is called "blocking", and Javascript shouldn't ever block. If you want to handle an event like a keypress, you should use a callback, and then continue the program from inside the callback.

So:

```
function myFunction (event) {
    //write the rest of your program in here
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", myFunction);

//you don't need anything down here
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to put the rest of the function to run inside the `keydown` callback, eg:

```
console.log('start');
document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  // put the rest of the code in here
  wait();
}, { once: true });
```

```js
console.log('start');
document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  // put the rest of the code in here
  console.log('rest of the code is running');
}, { once: true });
```

```html
click here first
```

Make sure to use `{ once: true }` so that the callback only runs once, otherwise other keydown events will result in running the `// put the rest of the code in here` again, which you don't want.

```js
console.log('start');
document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  // put the rest of the code in here
  console.log('rest of the code is running');
});
```

```html
click here first
```

If for some reason you *have* to stay in the same block and can't put the rest of the code into a separate function, you can `await` a Promise that resolves when the listener runs:

```
// in an async function:
console.log('start');
await new Promise((resolve) => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", resolve, { once: true });
});
// put the rest of the code in here
wait();
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  console.log('start');
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", resolve, { once: true });
  });
  // put the rest of the code in here
  console.log('rest of the code running');
});
```

```html
click here first
```

But that's pretty weird.